# same name for input type text and input type hidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am studying a mvc book that shows how search button works, it has uses same name for input type text and input type hidden, my problem is how action in the controller understands which parameter of search has to be used when submit the button when we have same names "search" for text box and hidden field

search text box there is in "_Layout.cshtml"

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.TextBox("Search", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search Products" })
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            }
```

and hidden field there is in "Index.cshtml"

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <label>Filter by category:</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(vm => vm.Category, Model.CatFilterItems, "All");
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Search" id="Search" value="@Model.Search" />
}
```

action index that gets parameters is like below:

```
   public ActionResult Index(string category, string search)
    {
        //instantiate a new view model
        ProductIndexViewModel viewModel = new ProductIndexViewModel();

        //select the products
        var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.Category);

        //perform the search and save the search string to the viewModel
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(search) ||
            p.Description.Contains(search) ||
            p.Category.Name.Contains(search));
            viewModel.Search = search;
        }

        //group search results into categories and count how many items in each category
        viewModel.CatsWithCount = from matchingProducts in products
                                  where
                                  matchingProducts.CategoryID != null
                                  group matchingProducts by
           matchingProducts.Category.Name into
                                  catGroup
                                  select new CategoryWithCount()
                                  {
                                      CategoryName = catGroup.Key,
                                      ProductCount = catGroup.Count()
                                  };

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.Category.Name == category);
        }

        viewModel.Products = products;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

s

Comment: You have 2 separate forms (and only one form can be submitted at once) at the value of the input with `name="search"` that is within the form will be posted to the controller

Comment: As a side note, if you did have multiple inputs in one form with `name="search"`, the `DefaultModelBinder` will only bind the first and ignore the rest (unless the method parameter was `IEnumerable<string> search`)

Comment: Thanks stephen , you mean search text box works separately of category dropdown list , i mean first i only search by text box and category is null and get first results and then in another form when i select category dropdown it uses value of search in hidden field for search parameter and value of drop down for category parameter

Comment: Yes, in the second form, the value of the hidden input will be populated with the value of the models `Search` property and will be posted back to the server when you submit it.

Comment: Thanks, my problem solved